# how do I properly call an exception in the lua interpreter

Tags: exception, lua

I am using lua 5.1

I want lua to fail a calculation and print an error if I try to divide a number by zero, raise zero number to a negative power, or modulo by zero.

what I did was change the calculation defines from something like this

```
#define luai_numdiv(L,a,b)  ((a)/(b))
```

to something like this

```
inline lua_number luai_numdiv(lua_State *L, lua_Number a, lua_Number b){
    if(b != cast_num(0))
        return (a)/(b);
     else
        luaD_throw(L, LUA_ERRRUN);
     }
```

this didn't work at all. and I believe it is related to luaD_Throw being an improper way to fail a calculation in lua.

how do I properly fail a calculation in lua?

Comment: Are you sure you're using Lua 5.1? `luai_numdiv` in 5.1 does not receive `L`. It does in 5.2.

Comment: I manually added it. wherever it was used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works. It just does not emit any error message.

Try adding `lua_pushliteral(L,"division by zero")` before `luaD_throw(L,LUA_ERRRUN)`.

Or use `luaG_runerror(L,"division by zero")`  instead of `luaD_throw(L,LUA_ERRRUN)` to get a  more informative error message.

Comment: will this also work for const folding? since I do get an error message when doing

    c = 5 / 0

and not when

    a = 5
    b = 0
    c = a / b

Comment: Interesting, I've never seen those functions. Why not luaL_error or lua_error?

Comment: Constant folding explicitly avoids division by zero. See `constfolding` in `lcode.c`.

Comment: The core does not call `lua_error` or `luaL_error` because it has to do some cleaning up.